# Getting bash: syntax error near unexpected token `(' in curl

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I get the error mentioned in question after running.

```
bash -c ("curl https://del.dog/raw/ayuhipalas")
```

Can anyone please tell me what is the proper syntax to be used in my case

Comment: Try `curl https://del.dog/raw/ayuhipalas | bash` if you like running untrusted code you found on the Internet...

Comment: @MarkSetchell That's my uploaded code sir , thanks for replying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax is

```
bash -c 'curl https://del.dog/raw/ayuhipalas'
```

Comment: I tried it but my commands doesn't run... it just displays the commands present in my del dog link and doesn't really do anything else.. ( i am sorry in advance if that's correct functionality ). Actually i want to execute all the linux commands from the del.dog link

Comment: I found the solution , although I would mark this as accepted as question was only regarding syntax